# what is the best way to have a bixby capsule collect a phone number?

Tags: bixby

What is the best way to collect a phone number? I struggled with this a few months ago, so maybe some things have been updated since then. I ended up creating a collect phone number action that would convert 10 concepts (one for each phone digit) to a string and then send that in an api call. I did not see a library capsule that took care of this but whether library capsule or not, is there a better way to collect a phone number? hopefully this question saves a lot of people the trouble of defining 10 concepts!

Answer (score 1):

You would not need a separate concept per digit; a `text` primitive concept that holds a full number is all you would need.

Additionally, using an `input-view` to show the user a [form](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/input-view.render.form) requesting their phone number would be the best method of implementing your use case.

This `input-view` `form` can be additionally modified with a `mask` attribute to ensure that invalid entries are checked as the user enters them. You can learn more about how to further customize your `mask` attribute [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/input-view.render.form.elements.text-input.pattern.mask) in our documentation.

For example, the following code snippet would only allow a phone number with the pattern (100) 000-0000.

```
text-input {
  id (pnumber)
  type (PhoneNumber)
  label (Phone Number)
  pattern {
    mask ("(100) 000-0000")
  }
  value ("#{raw(this.phoneNumber)}")
}
```

Comment: Cool this looks like it would solve a lot of cases, thanks! We are working on primarily voice interfaces though, is there something like mask for voice that would work without a form/view?